# Resource Not Found Error when using CLI batch-write-item

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli

First, I want to say that I am completely new at this. When trying to use the CLI to batch load items to my dynamodb, I get the following error:

An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the BatchWriteItem operation: Requested resource not found

The command I run is here:
    aws --no-verify-ssl dynamodb batch-write-item --request-items file://program.json

The JSON file contents are here:

```
{
    "Program": [
        {
            "PutRequest": { 
                "Item": {
                    "programName": {"S":"Yogi Bear"},
                    "activeInd": {"S":"Y"}
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "PutRequest": { 
                "Item": {
                    "programName": {"S":"Salad for Lunch"},
                    "activeInd": {"S":"Y"}
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I've compared this to the examples in the documentation and I can't see a problem. I tried to simple add an individual item using put-item and got the same error. If you have any suggestions, please let me know. Thanks in advance.`enter code here`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

### Verify that the "Program" table exists

From the DynamoDB documentation:

> ResourceNotFoundException
>
> Message: Requested resource not found.
>
> Example: Table which is being requested does not exist, or is too
>   early in the CREATING state.

In your JSON file, "Program" is intended to be the name of a table that already exists. It sounds like it is failing in both this batch and in your single put case simply because the table does not exist.

Check that this table already exists with the [list-tables](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/list-tables.html) command:

`aws dynamodb list-tables`

If not, create it with the [create-table](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/create-table.html#examples) command.

### Verify your CLI default region is the same as your table

If this table does exist, check your [cli configuration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html) to verify that you're querying in the same region that the table exists. You can check your default region like this:

```
aws configure get region
```

You can use `aws configure` to change your default settings, or specify `--region` directly on any CLI command to override your default region.

### Further Reading

- [AWS Documentation - aws dynamodb batch-write-item](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/batch-write-item.html#examples)
- [AWS Documentation - DynamoDB Error Handling](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Programming.Errors.html)
- [AWS Documentation - aws configure get](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/configure/get.html)

Comment: Thank you!  That was exactly it. I was in the wrong region. That has got me on a few occasions.

Comment: Region for me as well, when you know the table exists I guess that's where I should have gone next.

Comment: My Region and Table is correct still getting same issue.